# Find the rate of change in the radius when the radius is 6cm

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[The question, 1 (c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHgk3.jpg)

My attempt

$$A=12π(x^2 + \frac{16}{x})$$

Since $$r = 2x; r = 6, x = 3$$

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{dA}{dx}  \frac{dx}{dt} = 50$$

$$\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{ dr}{dx}$$

$$\frac{dA}{dx} = (12 π)( 2x - \frac{16}{x^2})$$

substitute $$x = 3 $$

$$into \frac{dA}{dx}$$

$$\frac{dA}{dx} = (12 π)[ 2(3) - \frac{16}{(3)^2}] = \frac{456 π}{9} = 159.19$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{50} {159.19} = 0.314$$

$$\frac{dr}{dx} = 2$$

Hence, $$\frac {dr}{dt} = (0.314)  \frac{dr} { dx} = (0.314)( 2) = 0.628$$

Comment: So, what is your problem? It is already okay, at least your logical reasonings and steps are okay

Comment: @guan721 : Please state your problem more clear.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ... But please don't use randomly chosen tags that are inappropriate, like differential geometry!

Comment: Hi, please refer to the The question, 1 (c), the attachment on the thread, as there is a diagram attached.

Comment: @guan721 : Hi, i mean its better if you state something that you want other to take care of like "Please check or take a look of my solution.." or sth.

Comment: I am sorry about it, I misunderstood you. The reason I post this question is because the answer from the text book is 0.3606, for the rate of change of radius when the radius is equal to 6. And I couldn't get the answer.